# Log file grep entries from last 30 min

Tags: awk, sed, scripting, perl, date

I am creating a script that will email errors/warnings from a log. I would like to have this sent every half hour but I only want to send it if there is a new entry. How would I grep out only the last half hour of errors?

The time stamp in the log is in the following format.

< Aug 1, 2016 2:15:29 PM MDT>  < Error details.....>

The script so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /var/log/logfile.log | egrep -i "error|warning" | tee -a /tmp/log.tmp

"get only last 30 min of errors" | mail -s "Errors/Warning" user@email.com
```

Is it possible to convert the time stamps (Aug 1, 2016 2:15:29 PM MDT) to epoch time then compare it to the current epoch time or is there a way with sed/awk/perl to get the last 30 minutes?

Comment: Get a baseline copy of your log file; run a script every 30 minutes and diff log file to the baseline file; massage the diff output to filter out extra characters; if there is a difference, send email with the difference lines in the context; make the current logfile the baseline file for the next run. This assumes you want to run this process continuously.

Comment: Does every line in the log contain a timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great ideas, the simplest is @MelBurslan suggestion to diff the files.

```
#!/bin/sh

MAILTO=user@email.com
OFILE=/var/tmp/alerts.tmp
LOG30=/var/tmp/LOG30
LOGNOW=/var/tmp/LOGNOW
HOST=`hostname`

# setup file
if [ -f ${OFILE} ]; then
  cat /dev/null > ${OFILE}
else
  touch ${OFILE}
fi


cat /var/log/logfile.log | egrep -i "error|warning" | tee -a ${LOGNOW}

diff ${LOG30} ${LOGNOW} | tee -a ${OFILE}

if [ -f ${OFILE} ]; then
  echo "Errors" | cat - ${OFILE} > temp && mv temp ${OFILE}
  mailx -r root@server.com -s "Errors" ${MAILTO} < ${OFILE}
fi

rm ${LOG30}
mv ${LOGNOW} /var/tmp/LOG30
rm ${OFILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

For conver to epoch, You can use the following statement :

```
# date +%s -d"Aug 1, 2016 2:15:29 PM MDT"
1470082529
```

For convert epoch to UTC, You can use :

```
# date -d @1470082529
Tue Aug  2 00:45:29 IRDT 2016  #### on Linux Box

# date -r 1470082529
Tue Aug  2 00:45:29 IRDT 2016 ###on BSD box
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`'s `File::Tail` module.  I don't have time to write an example now, but in perlish pseudocode, it would look something like this:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/not-actually-perl

use strict;
use File::Tail;

use Net::SMTP or Mail::Mailer or one of the squillion other
  perl mail sending modules;

open a File::Tail file handle to your log file

my $now=time();

my @lines = ();

while (read the File::Tail handle) {
  push @lines, $_;
  if (time() > ($now + 1800 seconds) ) {
    $now=time();
    email the @lines array to you@your.address;
    @lines=();
  }
}
```

An actual working script would probably be less than 10 lines longer than the above, and most of that would be setting up the headers for the email.

and a few more lines to trap various signals to email what it has now in @lines before suspending or quitting.

See the man pages for `File::Tail` and `Net::SMTP` (or whatever) for exact details.