# How can my postfix/spamcop learn from Gmail 421 rejections?

Tags: postfix

I have a number of vanity catch-all email domains. Back in the day, that was a good idea, and now it's too late to change for my friends and family.

I do not relay out, only serving incoming domains. Those incoming messages then get forwarded using mail aliases rules that each user locally configures. I am receiving mail and forwarding to user gmail inboxes using postfix. To make sure I filter out 90%+ of the spam, I run spamassassin with auto-update, as well as two RBL blocking lists and SPF records. Good mail does get through to Google, which is great!

Bad mail that still slips through the net ends up with a 421 temporary denial from Google. Typically Google will say "this is spam" or "this contains bad links" in the reject message, which is good as far as it goes, but I don't read the logs every hour and check every message.

Currently, I run a command that flushes the deferred queue once a day, so that I don't re-try the same spam too often. This is somewhat fragile, because a single message that arrives right before the flush, and then gets deferred once for some technical reason (TCP timeout etc) would also get deleted without delivery. Not great!

So, how can I go about training my spanassassin based on the messages received back from Google?
For now, I'm thinking of something that wakes up every 10 minutes, tails the mail.log file, and looks for 421 messages, extracts the message ID using regex, then runs postcat on that message, and feeds it to sa-learn for training.

First: Is something like this already available? I can't find anything obvious googling "spamassassin learn from gmail" or similar.

Second: Can you find anything wrong, missed assumption, etc, in my reasoning above that I should correct?

Comment: This is the kind of thing that `perl`'s `File::Tail` module is good for.  use File::Tail to monitor mail.log for 421 codes on delivery to google.  extract the queue-id and `postcat -bh` the deferred mail to `/usr/bin/sa-learn --spam ...`.   I use `sa-ham` and `sa-spam` aliases for training spamassasin (which i run from `amavisd-new`)...note: postfix runs `|` aliases as user nobody by default, so you'll need a second alias file owned by the user you run spamassassin as (in my case, that's user `amavis`)

Comment: alternatively, don't use an alias, run `sa-learn` directly from the File::Tail monitoring script, and run that script with the same uid that  you use to run spamassassin.

Comment: btw, I also use `formail` (from the `procmail` package) to strip `Resent-From` etc headers (I usually bounce spam that gets through my filters to `sa-spam`).  so my `sa-spam` alias looks like this: `sa-spam: "|/usr/bin/formail -I Resent-From -I Resent-Date -I Resent-Message-ID -I Resent-To -s | /usr/bin/sa-learn --spam --dbpath /var/lib/amavis/.spamassassin/"`

Comment: finally, `File::Tail` seemed appropriate for a quick answer I wrote last night.  it's just pseudocode, but it's still a useful example: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301545/7696

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It sounds like you're basically doing what I had come up with! (But as a persistent process.)
I have written perl before, and there are other languages I'd probably use if that's the way I go. (Including C -- nothing wrong with that :-)